# Iterator for custom 'dictionary with order' data structure

Tags: python, data-structures, iterator

For the application I'm working on, I need to store a set of items along with a probability associated with each item. I also need some way of consistently enumerating the items, so a defaultdict isn't that suitable for my purposes.

Currently I'm storing the items as a list of tuples with the item in the first slot, and the probability in the second.

```
mydata = zip(range(0,10), numpy.random.dirichlet([1]*10))
```

Is an example of the data structure (although there can be repeated keys, as I've described).

I'm going to wrap this up in a class but I want to iterate over it more like a dictionary than a list, and I'm not sure about how to go about writing this sort of code.

For example, I want to be able to say things like

```
tree = [[wt, [sym, ""]] for sym, wt in mydata.items()]
```

(This example is taken from the Rosetta code Huffman tree).

Is there something which already does this in Python, or something whose behaviour I could extend?

Comment: Take a look at [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: If I understand correctly, your `mydata` is a list of 2-tuples, so you could just iterate with  `tree = [[wt, [sym, ""]] for sym, wt in mydata]` I guess.

Comment: @JohannesCharra that throws a ValueError when I send it to the interpreter, and an AttributeError when I try to iterate over it,

Comment: @mouviciel does an OrderdDict allow for multiple repeated keys with unique values, or does it create a single key with multiple values?

Comment: @JohannesCharra's solution works... see http://codepad.org/2RowRbdV

Comment: When I suggested OrderedDict, I didn't notice your 'repeated keys' requirement. Unfortunately, an OrderedDict is a dict, so it doesn't allow the same key to be present several times.

Comment: @remram yes, I was doing something silly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyIter(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.idx = -1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.idx >= len(self.data) - 1:
            raise StopIteration

        self.idx += 1
        return {self.data[self.idx][0]: self.data[self.idx][1]}


mydata = zip(range(0,10), range(100,110))

for it in MyIter(mydata):
    print it
```

Dry Run:

```
Assuming mydata is:
[(0, 100), (1, 101), (2, 102), (3, 103), (4, 104), (5, 105), 
(6, 106), (7, 107), (8, 108), (9, 109), (1, 101)]

and the output is:
{0: 100}
{1: 101}
{2: 102}
{3: 103}
{4: 104}
{5: 105}
{6: 106}
{7: 107}
{8: 108}
{9: 109}
{1: 101}  # Note: Duplicate entry
```